# Subject RXJS auto reflesh angular doesnt work

Tags: angular, rxjs

i am trying to auto-refresh my table after i create a Task on Angular.

My home controller who include getTask method and the table:

home-component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.token){
      this.taskService.autoRefresh().subscribe(() => {
        this.getTasks();
      });
      this.getTasks();
    }
  }

  openModal() {
    this.dialog.open(CreateTaskComponent);
  }

  getTasks(): void {
    this.taskService.get(this.token).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        if (response) {
          this.tasks = response.tasks;
        }else{
          this.status = 'Aún no tienes creadas tareas';
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    );
  }
```

home-view:

```
<div *ngIf="tasks && tasks.length > 0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table mt-3">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                        <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                        <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let t of tasks">
                        <th scope="row">{{t.id}}</th>
                        <td>{{t.name}}</td>
                        <td [ngSwitch]="t.done">
                            <span *ngSwitchCase="0">Pendiente</span>
                            <span *ngSwitchCase="1">Hecho</span>
                        </td>
                        <td [ngSwitch]="t.done">
                            <span *ngSwitchCase="0">Hecho Editar Borrar</span>
                            <span *ngSwitchCase="1">Borrar</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My create component (who include Modal)

```
  onSubmit(): void {
    const task: ITask = this.createTaskForm.value
    this.taskService.create(task, this.token).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        if (response) {
          this.status = `Tarea ${response.task.name} creada!`;
        } else{
          this.status = 'Error al crear la tarea!';
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    );
  }
```

my task service:

```
  private _subject = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  autoRefresh(){
    return this._subject;
  }
  
  create(task: ITask, token: string): Observable<any> {

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set(
      'Content-Type',
      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    )
    .set('Authorization', token);

    const body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('name', task.name);


    const url = `${apiUrl}create`;

    return this._http.post(url, body.toString(), { headers: headers }).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this._subject.next();
      })
    );
  }

  get(token: string | null): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${apiUrl}get-tasks/${token}`;

    return this._http.get(url);
  }
```

Why isn't it working? It doesn't give me any error or anything, it just ignores the Subject as if it didn't exist or wasn't properly applied. I hope you can help me. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Method autoRefresh() should look like:

```
autoRefresh() {
 this._subject.asObservable();
}
```

Because you want to subscribe to the subject therefor it has to be returned as observable.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

Try something like this:

Your task service:

```js
private _subject = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  autoRefresh(){
    return this._subject.asObservable();
  }

  // new method
  refreshTable() {
    this._subject.next();
  }
  
  create(task: ITask, token: string): Observable<any> {

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set(
      'Content-Type',
      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    )
    .set('Authorization', token);

    const body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('name', task.name);


    const url = `${apiUrl}create`;

    return this._http.post(url, body.toString(), { headers: headers })
  }

  get(token: string | null): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${apiUrl}get-tasks/${token}`;

    return this._http.get(url);
  }
```

Your create component:

```js
onSubmit(): void {
    const task: ITask = this.createTaskForm.value
    this.taskService.create(task, this.token).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        if (response) {
          this.status = `Tarea ${response.task.name} creada!`;
          
          // call the new method "refreshTable()"
          this.taskService.refreshTable();
        } else{
          this.status = 'Error al crear la tarea!';
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: I tried it but doesnt work anyway. I think the problem comes when I call `autoRefresh()` on the `home-component` since I pass a `console.log` to it inside the subscribe and it doesn't log anything. EDIT: if i log into `autoRefresh()` method (inside service) works. But not into subscribe on `ngOnInit`

Comment: I would focus on "tap" inside of create() method. I think this is not called. Because pipe operator "tap" is usually used right before ".subscribe()" as you can see [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap). In the service create a new method, which will call "this._subject.next()". And call it from method "onSubmit()" after subscription is successful.

Comment: I found the bug. The problem is that I have the get inside a home component and the create in another component loaded with a modal inside the home view. Creating from there doesn't work correctly... I don't know if there would be a solution to this...